# Error with Truffle React (the contract doesn't have address)

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, react, truffle-deployment

Someone knows something about this error with Truffle React box? Must be my Metamask wallet address but it is already in my `truffle-config` file.

[image]

I leave the App.js file here (I didn't make it. It's just the code of Truffle React Box). I've just followed the steps here: https://www.trufflesuite.com/boxes/react

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SimpleStorageContract from "./contracts/SimpleStorage.json";
import getWeb3 from "./getWeb3";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = { storageValue: 0, web3: null, accounts: null, contract: null };

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    try {
      // Get network provider and web3 instance.
      const web3 = await getWeb3();
      // Use web3 to get the user's accounts.
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

      // Get the contract instance.
      const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
      const deployedNetwork = SimpleStorageContract.networks[networkId];
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );


      // Set web3, accounts, and contract to the state, and then proceed with an
      // example of interacting with the contract's methods.
      this.setState({ web3, accounts, contract: instance }, this.runExample);
    } catch (error) {
      // Catch any errors for any of the above operations.
      alert(
        `Failed to load web3, accounts, or contract. Check console for details.`,
      );
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  runExample = async () => {
    const { accounts, contract } = this.state;

    // Stores a given value, 5 by default.
    await contract.methods.set(5).send({ from: accounts[0] });

    // Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
    const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

    // Update state with the result.
    this.setState({ storageValue: response });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.state.web3) {
      return <div>Loading Web3, accounts, and contract...</div>;
    }
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Good to Go!</h1>
        <p>Your Truffle Box is installed and ready.</p>
        <h2>Smart Contract Example</h2>
        <p>
          If your contracts compiled and migrated successfully, below will show
          a stored value of 5 (by default).
        </p>
        <p>
          Try changing the value stored on <strong>line 42</strong> of App.js.
        </p>
        <div>The stored value is: {this.state.storageValue}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**SOLUTION:**

After this piece of code:

```
      const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );
```

I've added this line:

`instance.options.address = "[my contract' address on kovan]"`

Comment: is truffle still used? I thought it was a relic

Comment: @Nulik is there another way to make your DApp "easily"? I'm just starting with DApps and there're lot of things to learn.

Comment: many people use hardhat, check it out

Comment: I'll check it out but... I'd like to try with Truffle and work with React framework.

Comment: Where do you "declare" the contract?

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate I think it's Line 20 (I updated the Question with my code):       `const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
        SimpleStorageContract.abi,
        deployedNetwork && deployedNetwork.address,
      );`

My wallet is connected and working with kovan network. Moreover, I can see my contract' address when I execute `migrate`, but I don't understand what's happening here...

Comment: I know this might sound simple; but try changing 'const' to 'var' and let me know what happens

Comment: @AvocadoChocolate exactly the same error :(

Comment: I found a solution (post updated). Thanks so much for help guys!